# What is the recommended way to package up pre-configured solace docker image

Tags: docker, solace

We are trying to package up a solace docker image with pre configured message vpn, jndi connection factory, queues and such. This is so that we can take the docker image to a different site and load it there without having to configure it on every site.

Is all the configuration information that I have done from Solace UI stored in `/usr/sw/var` within container environment? So in reality all I have to do is save contents of that directory and build a new docker image with that contents?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the configuration information that you have done is stored in directory /usr/sw/var. But it contains a lot more than you want, like hostname, router-name and other data that you do not really want.

If I may suggest, the best way to 'copy' your data is to go into the Solace CLI and do:

> show current-config message-vpn *

You can re-direct the data to a file e.g.

> show current-config message-vpn * > my-vpn-config.txt

The output is saved in the directory /usr/sw/jail.
You can edit this file if you like, it will contain CLI commands that are familiar to you.

Copy this file out and download it to your new docker directory under /usr/sw/jail. From there you can source your configuration file with the command:

> enable
>
> source script my-vpn-config.txt

With the above method, you will miss out some system configurations, like usernames, ldap-profile, etc.. But from the list of things you are looking for 'message vpn, jndi connection factory, queues and such', this is good enough.